# iPhone will not connect to my wifi

Tags: iphone, wifi

My iPhone says its connected to wifi but it won't let me surf the web. My iPad is using the same connection and I don't have a problem with it. Does anyone have any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Is this a home wifi, or a public wifi at a restaurant (or something similar)?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any IP address assigned? And if so, does it come from your router? (e.g., is it in the same range as a computer or other device that is connected to the same router? ) If it happens to start with 169.254.x.x, then there probably is something wrong with one of the router settings (probably DHCP not configured properly), as that indicates that your iPhone has a self-assigned IP-address.

You can check the IP-address by opening the Settings app, tapping Wi-Fi, and tap the blue information-icon (i) next to the connected Wi-Fi network. And are the iPad and iPhone the only two devices connected to that router? Or are there other devices that are successfully connected as well?

Answer (score 1):

The network settings may be corrupt on your iPhone.

Open the Settings app and choose >> General >> Reset >> Reset Network Settings

This will wipe all previous settings for any wifi networks you've joined in the past and remove any cell tower connection history your phone has stored in memory.  Once the phone reboots it will look for the closest cell tower.  Then join your home WIFI as you normally would.

If that doesn't work its possible you may have more serious issues with your phone.  Can you join other WIFI networks?